# Shift register activating transistor doesn't work as expected

Tags: arduino, transistors, 74hc595

I'm trying to make a led cube by multiplexing by floor. I'm using 74hc595 shift register to extent arduino output and transistor for alimenting led. But while doing some tests, I had some problems with the transistors: When I want to light one led per level (for example the green and the black one), the two others light up slightly too. By adding delay in the arduino code, I can limit this problem or even remove it, but losing the retinal persistence.
To test if the problem was coming from the 74hc595, I did the test by removing the transistors and directly powering the leds from the 74hc595, and I don't have this problem anymore. So I guess the problem comes somehow from the transistors or from my electrical circuit.

Here are the schematic with the transtor that does not work and the one without that work fine
[image: with the transistor (don't work)]
[image: without the transistor (working fine)]

I know I should use a capacitor between VCC and GND for the 74hc595 but I don't have any and it work fine without transistor so I don't think it comes from that. For information, I use the SPI.transfer function to communicate between arduino and 74hc595.

Is it possible that the transistor cannot switch fast enough for this use ? Or it is a bad design ?

Comment: The 74HC595's output enable is hardwired to ground (always on). If I were a guessing man I'd say there's some bit combinations passing by while shifting data in at high speed that briefly enables the LED's and this can be visible. Connect the output enable to your Arduino and modify the code to disable the outputs while data is being shifted in. Only enable the outputs when the data is stable.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was exactly that. I thought about this kind of problem, but I didn't think about using the output enable. I also use a 10 microsecond delay before activating the outputs after the data shift.Without this little delay, the leds stay a little bit lit.